# Figuring Out Which Gems Rails App Does Not Use

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Working on an app that has almost 200 gems. Has anyone figured out how to isolate gems that are not used so they can be taken out of the mix.

Comment: The only way I know of to do this is to remove them one-by-one and see if things break. This is made much easier if you have full test coverage. Knowing *what* the gems do makes it easier to guess which ones are no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks. It would take a while but that is probably the only sure way to do it. Unless there was something that looked at the methods each gem extended and then greped the app.

Comment: As @AndrewMarshall said, it is probably better to add (full) test coverage. Assuming you application is big, it takes a lot of time to test every thing when one gem is removed. After that again when another gem is removed, and so on...

Comment: True, true... though it would be nice to have info on what and where your gems are used :)

Comment: You could find out which ones actually get required by examining `$"`. which ones's get used is much harder.

Comment: I think because of the gem file they are all required, except for all of the gems that we require as `gem some_gem, require:nil`

Comment: You might try executing a coverage run with rcov, specifying you want rcov to include your gems library in the coverage inspection (eg `--include-file /usr/lib/ruby/gems`). Then use the coverage report to show you which gems actually had code executed.

Comment: @Codeglot bundle exec doesn't automatically require gems from gemfile, it just assures that when required, you get the right one. Just verified that by making a gemfile soecifying rspec, doing bundle install, then `bundle exec ruby -e'puts $".select{|x| x =~ /rspec/}'` and `bundle exec ruby -e'require "rspec"; puts $".select{|x| x =~ /rspec/}'`

Answer (score 3):

Due to the dynamic nature of Ruby, it's not possible to know for sure if a gem is or isn't used without testing. Although it is bad practice to load them in ad-hoc without a good reason, it is possible to require a gem at any point in the execution of the program. They do not need to be loaded up-front.

Although there might be advantages to loading gems on demand, for instance, keeping a lower memory footprint and reducing launch times, it does make it difficult to determine if or where they are actually used.

There isn't always a correlation between a gem name and the methods it uses. While many have a namespace that's easily grepped for, some just add methods to existing classes which can complicate tracking them down, especially if they go so far as to patch out old methods with new ones that have the same name.

If you are able to exercise a large portion of the application through your unit, functional, and integration tests it might be possible to use [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) to at least get a sense of which gems are used. That could make identifying candidates for removal easier.

Comment: `Due to the dynamic nature of Ruby...` - what about loading all methods from each gem, and then greping for them in the app, only returning gem/method paris if greater than 0, and for class methods just sub the class name, etc...? I think it's possible. No?

Comment: Some gems generate their methods automatically, so you never really know what the methods are going to be called. It's one of those things that's fundamentally unknowable because of the flexibility afforded by design. You can only guess, you can never be assured. The amount of certainty you have grows as your test coverage increases, though.

Comment: there are also gems that only provide static assets.